# cannot install ubuntu using dual boot......main problem is with partioning the system after entering into ubuntu using flash drive

Tags: boot-partition

I have made partition of my  hard drive and created a bootable pendrive with Ubuntu 12.04 i386 then rebooted my system using pendrive...........then Ubuntu started but......... I want to install permanently along with windows 8 but I have difficulty in partitioning the things after this in Ubuntu...for example how to create swap area etc., ..........I followed the video in YouTube in which after entering into the Ubuntu system he has give a double click on the "free space" after that he created everything.......but in my system I can't find the tag called "free space" to click on that but there is one more thing called "unusable" on which the double click wont work to do partition......so please help me to partition the things.....and one more thing is that I have give a sufficient hard disk space for that i.e. 70 gb for Ubuntu ..but this partition is made from f drive in windows not from c drive.....
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. You can install Ubuntu along with windows 8. Better check this site and follow the steps mentioned over there.
[Install Ubuntu on windows 8](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
This will certainly help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have too many partitions.

You will be able to install Ubuntu if you have less than 4 partitions on your disk (windows 8 will probably create a "loader" partition along the ones you already have).
Also be sure to check that you do not have the disk partitioned as a dynamic disk.
In that case you will have to transform it back to normal.

It does not matter what the letter is, but be sure when installing not to overwrite MBR with Ubuntu as it will probably mean you will not be able to boot into Windows.

You have to install Grub onto Ubuntu partition.

Then you will have to install EasyBCD in windows (do not forget to install NeoGrub inside the app), and everything should work fine.